# JS counter when scroll to a div stop counting

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to make a counter on javascript that when you go to certain div, start counting and when you reach the specified number it stops, and if I continue scrolling, the counter no longer keep counting

I have made a Pen with the idea, but when I continue scrolling the counter do not stop, and start to count down, and then stop when reach a low number.

Any idea to make this work?

Thanks in advance.

**HTML**

```
<!-- Counter section -->
<div id="counter" class="Wrapper-counter">
  <!-- Counter_item -->
  <div class="Counter_item">
    <h3 class="Counter_h3 right">
      <span class="count">
        123
      </span>
    </h3>
    <p class="Counter_paragraph right">
      <strong>Lorem ipsum</strong>
    </p>
  </div>
  <!-- /Counter_item -->

  <!-- Counter_item -->
  <div class="Counter_item">
    <h3 class="Counter_h3 left">
      <span class="count">
        123
      </span>
    </h3>
    <p class="Counter_paragraph left">
      <strong>Lorem ipsum</strong>
    </p>
  </div>
  <!-- /Counter_item -->
</div>
<!-- /Counter section -->
```

**JS**

```
$(window).on('scroll', function() {

  var div_counter = window.pageYOffset;
  var scroll_pos_test = $('#counter').offset().top - window.innerHeight; // set to whatever you want it to be

  if(div_counter < scroll_pos_test) {
        //do stuff
      $('.count').each(function () {
        $(this).prop('Counter',0).animate({
          Counter: $(this).text()
        }, {
          duration: 3000,
          easing: 'swing',
          step: function (now) {
            $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
          }
        });
      });
    }
});
```

[codepen here](http://codepen.io/rasalghul/pen/jWXBve/)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand your code, but I created an example of what you are looking for which might give you a new perspective of how to tackle this problem in an easier way. Check out the working example on [**CODEPEN**](http://codepen.io/zero_point/pen/YwdByQ).

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
   <p data-counter="100">100</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
p {
  font-size: 3em;
  position: fixed;
  color: blue;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  height: 700px;
  background: #ccc;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var topCount = 100;
  var maxCount = 50;
  var startCount = 200;
  var endCount = 400;
  var currCount = 0;

  $(window).scroll(function() {

    if (($(window).scrollTop() >= startCount) && ($(window).scrollTop() <= endCount)) {

      currCount = Math.floor(maxCount + (maxCount - topCount) * ($(window).scrollTop() - endCount) / (endCount - startCount));

     $("p").attr("data-counter",currCount).text(currCount);
    }
 });
});
```

It should be pretty straight-forward. I don't have a resetting mechanism since I don't know how you want to do it or if you want to have it at all. but it is easy to add any modification

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the code but it is not what I was looking; I solved the problem by adding the plugin [INVIEW JQUERY](https://github.com/protonet/jquery.inview) and the following script, thanks anyway

> [CODEPEN DEMO](http://codepen.io/rasalghul/pen/jWXBve/)

```
$('#counter').bind('inview', function(event, visible, visiblePartX, visiblePartY) {
    if (visible) {
        $(this).find('.count').each(function () {
            var $this = $(this);
            $({ Counter: 0 }).animate({ Counter: $this.text() }, {
                duration: 2000,
                easing: 'swing',
                step: function () {
                    $this.text(Math.ceil(this.Counter));
                }
            });
        });
        $(this).unbind('inview');
    }
});
```